# xarray: reverse an array along one coordinate

Tags: python-xarray

For my data array I have coordinates longitude and latitude and time. I want to reverse the array along latitude only so that `[90, 85, ..., -80, -90]` becomes `[-90, -80, ..., 85, 90]`.

Comment: I recommend asking a specific question and showing what you have tried that isn't working.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Agree with @jhamman's response that a minimally reproducible example would help

I think you could use

```
da = xr.tutorial.open_dataset('air_temperature')
da.reindex(lat=list(reversed(da.lat)))
```

Comment: This worked - I found `da.reindex(lat=da.lat[::-1])`to be a little faster. Many thanks!

Comment: I thought this doesn't work, until I realized that the `reindex()` function is not in-place, you have to assign the return value to something (possible the original variable).

Answer (score 6):

Base on [this discussion](https://github.com/pydata/xarray/discussions/6695), another option is to use `isel` to get a reversed view:

```py
da = xr.tutorial.open_dataset('air_temperature')
da.isel(lat=slice(None, None, -1)
```

I've found this approach to work better with large datasets backed by dask arrays. The `reindex` approach in @Maximilian's answer causes the data to be rechunked into very large chunks. This approach avoids that.